Sync pl.StringCache / Categorical encoding across machines in polars
I need polars Categorical data type to have the same physical representation across different machines. On one machine, I can use pl.StringCache to get the same physical representation:
with pl.StringCache():
    s1 = pl.Series("color", ["red", "green", "red"], dtype=pl.Categorical)
    s2 = pl.Series("color", ["blue", "red", "green"], dtype=pl.Categorical)

But I need to replicate the same physical encoding on a totally different machine:
with pl.StringCache():
    s1 = pl.Series("color", ["red", "green", "red"], dtype=pl.Categorical)
    # Somhow save encoding here

# On a different machine
with pl.StringCache(): # Somehow load encoding here
    s2 = pl.Series("color", ["blue", "red", "green"], dtype=pl.Categorical)

It seems to be not possible at the time, but are there any workarounds?
My use case is machine learning. I'm training a model on categorical data on one machine, and I need the encoding for inference on different machines. While I could technically use a Scikit learn label encoder, I would like to stay in polars.

You could probably save the unique values of s1 to disk and load it within the pl.StringCache() context on the inference machine.

Is the physical representation with StringCache deterministic, if the data is sorted?

This is not supported to do automatically with Categorical. You will have to calculate the categories yourself and bake them into an pl.Enum.

Can I then convert pl.Enum into a categorical? Some Frameworks use more appropriate functions for categorical if the data type is correct.
